Is it possible to build an up-to-date version of the g++ (14/13) on Raspberry Pi running Debian 12 arm64?
I am puzzled. There is seemingly no newer Debian image for Raspberry Pi than the current stable version 12 (bookworm). I have downloaded and installed it just when it went out without issues, I remember. Link to all tested images here. My Pi's HW is 4 (8GB). Just to be clear, I am all Ok with Debian's aim to be rock-stable. Just one thing, if I may poke.

I wonder if it is possible to build an up-to-date version of the g++ (14) on my arm64 Raspberry Pi running Debian 12? (Today, I somewhat needed it, but found out, an older g++-12 available only, it caused me only minor trouble this time.)
And if yes, how would I proceed exactly? I have no clue.

Here is what g++ versions I found available on Linux Mint 22 (based on Ubuntu Noble), i.e. version 10+:
$ apt-cache policy g++-1[0-9] | grep -A 2 '^g++-1'

g++-10:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 10.5.0-4ubuntu2
--
g++-11:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 11.4.0-9ubuntu1
--
g++-12:
  Installed: 12.3.0-17ubuntu1
  Candidate: 12.3.0-17ubuntu1
--
g++-13:
  Installed: 13.3.0-6ubuntu2~24.04
  Candidate: 13.3.0-6ubuntu2~24.04
--
g++-14:
  Installed: 14.2.0-4ubuntu2~24.04
  Candidate: 14.2.0-4ubuntu2~24.04

For reference, here are currently available versions on Pi's Debian 12, i.e. versions 10+, as above:
$ apt-cache policy g++-1[0-9] | grep -A 2 '^g++-1'

g++-10:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
--
g++-11:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 11.3.0-12
--
g++-12:
  Installed: 12.2.0-14
  Candidate: 12.2.0-14
--
g++-13:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)


Nope, no sign of g++-14, not even g++-13 available (yet). So, my question above stands. Thank you in advance.

Warning
@StephenKitt points out that the below is a dangerous operation, as you can end up with a broken system (the VM I tried this on is fine, but that wasn't an arm64 VM nor had any graphical frontend installed).
Your alternative is to get the .dsc file from packages.debian.org's trixie gcc 14, and then build that using dpkg-buildpackage. The instructions for GCC12 on Ubuntu 20.04 I wrote in this answer would solve your issue as well, but would require compiling from source.
Main text
Debian can let you set up "mixed" package sources, where you only pull in packages from the "newer" distro release when explicitly asked to/strictly necessary.
For that, you'd

add a trixie (current testing release of debian) repo
tell apt that it shouldn't use that by default
explicitly install gcc from that repo

1. add a trixie (current testing release of debian) repo
copy the current repo specification
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.sources /etc/apt/sources.list.d/triixie.sources

and modify pixie.sources to only list trixie; it should be, afterwards:
Types: deb
URIs: http://deb.debian.org/debian
Suites: trixie
Components: main
Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg

2. tell apt that it shouldn't use that by default
create a file nvim /etc/apt/preferences.d/99debian-trixie, containing:
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 100

Test that this did work:
apt update
apt-cache policy
## This should now list the new trixie repository, at priority 100,
## and the default bullseye repo should still be at priority 500
apt-cache policy gcc
## Should now list GCC 14 from trixie as low-priority alternative to
## the default gcc.

3. explicitly install gcc from that repo
(and while we're at it, the usual build tools also in their more modern trixie version)
apt install -t trixie gcc g++ gdb cmake clang-format


Wow, so it's possible even without compiling! I will try that up once I have a little extra time. Thank you!

the alternative is using dpkg-buildpackage to build the gcc (14) package from trixie on bullseye with debian tooling itself. Though, if doing that, you can probably also just set up an schroot on a beefy x86_64 "compile machine" (assuming you have that instead of a beefy arm64 machine) and use sbuild --host=arm64 … to cross-build the packages for the Raspberry Pi. The machine compiling source code doesn't have to have the same CPU as the machine running the result!

Given GCC’s dependencies, installing the trixie package on Debian 12 will pull in lots of other packages from trixie (including libc6), which isn’t a great idea. You’d be better off rebuilding GCC or using a trixie container.

@StephenKitt not going to contradict that installing GCC from testing on your debian stable makes your computer more of a "debian testing machine with most of a stable userland and kernel" than a "stable" machine. my experiences with that have been OK, but then again, I'm also someone to recommend rebuilding the package yourself, so maybe I'm more tolerant to misfunction/failure than most.

Your first paragraph gives the impression that this setup is innocuous, and that only the requested packages get upgraded. That’s not the case, and especially with the t64 transition in Debian 13, it’s not all that difficult to end up with a broken system. I dare say Vlastimil and you could avoid trouble, but remember that others read these answers too.

@StephenKitt I prepended a warning, and linked to the answer where I explain how you can do a gcc packaging backport on a debian derivative

Thanks. I’m not the only one warning about such setups — there’s even a name for them, FrankenDebian. And while I’m sure you did test this, and it works fine now, the problem with these setups is that they’re liable to break in future — in particular, when the next version of Debian is released. Mixing a stable distribution with a rolling distribution is inherently risky; and if core packages such as libc6 are upgraded, that might lock the user out of tested upgrade paths.

An example scenario where this can leave a user stuck is if, during the development of Debian 13, an upgrade issue is discovered that requires a fix in Debian 12. This will be provided in a Debian 12 point-release, and is one of the reasons why the release notes always say that the first step in upgrading to release n+1 is to make sure the system is fully updated with respect to release n. Installing a newer package from Debian 13 during Debian 13’s development means that such point-release fixes to the upgraded packages won’t be applied.

@StephenKitt thanks! yeah, that's pretty clear.
